# Calling NodeJs script from Powershell - Encoding problem

Tags: node.js, powershell

I have a JavaScript file "test.js" and want to call this file from PowerShell.

test.js file:

```
async function main() {
  console.log("€");
}

main();
```

When I call the script from cmd I get the correct encoded result like "€"

```
C:\> node test.js -> €
```

When I call the script from PowerShell I get a wrong encoded result like "â‚¬"

```
PS C:\> node test.js -> â‚¬
```

When I call the script from PowerShell via cmd  I get also a wrong encoded result like "â‚¬"

```
PS C:\> cmd /c node test.js -> â‚¬
```

What can I do the get the correct encoded result "€" in PowerShell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the encoding of your powershell host to UTF 8, nodejs is using this encoding by default.

```
[console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
```